# uint32, int16, uint8 .. Why these commonly used data types are not making it into the standards

Tags: c++, c

Over the years across multiple orgs and various projects involving C/C++ I have seen the need for fixed-width integers has been addressed by defining a local version of `types.h` which would mostly look like this:-

```
typedef  signed char        int8;
typedef  unsigned char      uint8;
typedef  signed short       int16;
typedef  unsigned short     uint16;
typedef  signed long        int32;
typedef  unsigned long      uint32
typedef  signed long long   int64;
typedef  unsigned long long uint64;
```

Why are these not getting integrated into C/C++ standards?

I know `C99` has standardized the likes of `uint32_t`. Similarly Microsoft has defined it's own `UINT32` etc.. - But these still requires `typedef` s since 
usage of uintX lingo is widespread among legacy as well as new code written by seasoned developers

Am also aware of [Boost Integer Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/integer/index.html) - Again that's not standard C++ as they clearly mention:-

> Because these are boost headers, their names conform to boost header
>   naming conventions rather than C++ Standard Library header naming
>   conventions.

Thoughts on pros an cons of integrating `[u]intX` s into the official standards?

**EDIT**:
The question has generated quality answers and *opinions* already. Thanks they are informative and helpful!! Some comments suggest the question is not clear enough:-
*"you're asking specifically about adding more aliases for the already-existing typedefs in the standard"* - Yes precisely

**@Pascal Cuoq**'s ans addresses the real issue in case these were to be added to the standards: -

> Do not wait for the name `uint32` to become the official name of an
>   integer type in C++; it will probably never happen, ***precisely because
>   so many programs are already typedef'ing a type to this name***.

Comment: But we have `stdint.h`.

Comment: @GillBates: Yes - but that has tje `_t` variants - am talking about the `[u]intX` s

Comment: That's just a naming convention `_t` is usually used for types.

Comment: I don't see `uint32` more commonly used than `u32`

Comment: `int9`, `int13`, `int24`, `int32`, `int48`, `int64`, `int100`, `int128`, `int256`, `int384`, ... where do you stop (the Standard)??

Comment: Oh, you're asking specifically about adding more aliases for the already-existing typedefs in the standard. That was not very clear, can I recommend editing?

Comment: @pmg: Presumablhy with the widths natively supported by the target platform. Personally I have on occasion missed the intermediate `[u]int_leastX_t` widths not provided by `<stdint.h>` in writing portable code targeting oddball platforms.

Comment: Yes, I always wanted an `int_which_can_hold_a_unicode_character` name! Seriously: what's your problem with `uintN_t`? Too much to type? Get an editor with autocompletion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C99 introduced the header `stdint.h` (7.18), and C++11 imported it as `<cstdint>`.

You may be asking why the names of types in there are `uint32_t` instead of `uint32`. Simple: because then the names would clash with existing code.

POSIX had reserved the `_t` suffix for types. (You are not supposed to use `_t` for any type in your program, if you want to to be compatible with current and future POSIX systems. This is a common mistake that even experienced programmers make). POSIX had also used its reserved namespace to safely define type names in the `uint32_t` format.

C99 chose the same names as POSIX. From the point of view of the C committee, it was unlikely these names would break existing programs (backwards compatibility is a very important consideration when evolving the C language). Later, when they appeared in C++, there was more value in keeping compatibility between C++ and C than in choosing different names.

Do not wait for the name `uint32` to become the official name of an integer type in C++; it will probably never happen, precisely because so many programs are already `typedef`'ing a type to this name.

Comment: C99 adds `(u)int*_t` because POSIX already had `(u)int*_t`. Your explanation is right for why POSIX chose those names though.

Comment: @hvd: That's exactly what I was trying to ask - may be I did not frame the question correctly - Pls feel free to edit it

Comment: @hvd Oh that's interesting! I wrote that the `*_t` namespace for types was reserved by POSIX, but deleted that mention from POSIX since it didn't fit with the rest. I shall introduce it again. tbh I'm not sure what the OP is asking, so fair enough if I'm not answering it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq If the OP thinks it does answer the question, then who am I to disagree? I removed my mention of that. It was an interesting post regardless.

Answer (score 4):

Actually they are part of C++ 11 standard but with the `_t` suffix:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

to **not deviate from other common types and hold on the naming scheme**. That would be very counter-intuitive to have some standard types ending with `_t` and some not.

But some of them are *optional*, because underlying hardware might have no support for them. And thus there are some counterparts like `int_least8_t`, which have the size of at least 8 bits:

> smallest signed integer type with width of at least 8 bits

such a type in turn allows to guarantee the portability.

You can't/shouldn't put things to a standard which are not portable, that would disallow usage of the language on a particular platform.

**How much code breaks?** In addition to upper thoughts, what I was reading from previous C++ standards committee meetings: When a new feature is going to be introduced a reference implementation is made and compilation tests are run on existing code, to find out how much code this feature might break. For example, this was the case when changing the `auto` keyword meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The typedefs with `_t` suffixes have existed as part of a different official standard since the late '90s, possibly earlier, that's why it's those versions that got incorporated into the C and C++ standards.

People using different typedefs when standard typedefs already exist is their problem. Duplicating a whole list of typedefs in the standard just creates a bigger mess.